# Add splash screen to Clickonce application

Tags: c#, clickonce, splash-screen

I have written an ClickOnce application. Now my customer asks for a Splash screen when the application updates and starts. Is there a way to hook in the update process of ClickOnce to show a splash screen?

The splashscreen will have a splash screen logo and a description of what it is doing at the moment. For example: Starting application, Updating application, ...

On some forums I have found some ways but they also change the update process. I don't want to change the update process of ClickOnce.

Is there a way to accomplish this in my Clickonce application?

Comment: Well, i think you could do that but maybe you'd need to check versions and update the application manually. Check [`System.Deployment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt481532(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace. e.g., using [`UpdateCheckInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.updatecheckinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) you can check if a new version is available in the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do it by code look at this [link](http://dennis.bloggingabout.net/2007/11/05/manual-check-for-updates-with-clickonce/) for a sample  for how to update by code you need too create form for this at first you check the update and if there was an update before run the program run your splash screen after that program will be start if you want i can give you full sample.